# Bandsaw tyre jumps off

Tags: woodworking, maintenance, bandsaw

I have a small 250W table-top bandsaw.
I was doing quite a long cut the other day, and after a a while there was a sudden noise, and the tyre on the upper pulley jumped off.
I put it back on again, with a little difficulty, as I couldn't see any damage to it, but it jumped off again immediately.
Is there anything else I should look at, or just assume that the tyre needs to be replaced?

Comment: Would inspect everything again for misalignment, loose fitting/not tight enough, etc.  Re-read instructions for proper setup.

Answer (score 6):

Tyre could need replacing if it is worn to the point that it is not maintaining the correct shape on its outside diameter when installed. Ideally the center across its width should present a slightly larger diameter than the outer edges. This causes the blade to want to ride in the center of the wheel.

The tyre may also have lost much of its rubbery texture due to age or accumulation of fine sawdust. An aged tyre needs replacement. I have had luck with cleaning a type that was still reasonably pliable.

You may also want to check the wheel alignment. If one wheel is slightly canted with respect to the other this can cause the blade to come off the wheels. Tension can be also be an adjustment that needs to be made.

Comment: Fixing this problem was an exercise in high school wood shop. You passed.